# Need to show/hide a button depending on the page

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to hide back button on site-header that takes me to dashboard. I am using pod structure that is something like this:

- pod

  - component

    - site-header

      - template.hbs
      - component.js
  - main

    - dashboard

In the component.js I used computed to get current route

```js
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Component.extend({
router: service (),
 dashboard:computed('currentRouteName',function(){
    if(this.get('currentRouteName') === 'main.dashboard.index'){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
})
})
```

In template.hbs I used the following code to check the link.

```html
{{#unless dashboard}}
  {{#link-to "main.dashboard" class="back-btn"}}{{t "goBackToDashboard"}}{{/link-to}}
{{/unless}}
```

Still it is the same by tweaking the if/else conditions also I either get the button on all pages or on none.
Any help will be appreciated.

app/route.js:

```js
import EmberRouter from '@ember/routing/router';
import config from './config/environment';
import { inject } from '@ember/service';
import $ from 'jquery';
const Router = EmberRouter.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL,
  ajax: inject('ajax'),
});

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('login', { path: 'login' });
  this.route('main', { path: '/' }, function () {
    this.route('dashboard', { path: '' }, function () {});
    this.route("review", { path: "/review/:docId" }, function() { // eslint-disable-line
      this.route("edit", { path: "/edit/:bitId" }); // eslint-disable-line
      this.route('window_edit');
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you tell us what Ember version you are on?

Comment: Does `main.dashboard` route has any child routes? Would be helpful if you could include your `app/router.js`. If you fixed your code as per @locks answer you may still check against a wrong route name. The `main.dashboard.index` is only the route name if `main.dashboard` has at least one child route.

Comment: @jelhan I added app/route.js code. Will be great help if you can check that out. And I also tried `if(this.get('currentRouteName') === 'main.dashboard')` and the outcome is the same and let me know if you want to see my other route.js where i defined the routes

Comment: I meant `app/router.js`. The file in which you registers the routes. It seems as if you shared some `Route` but not the router file itself. I'm talking about the file discussed [in this chapter of the Ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/defining-your-routes/).

Comment: Thanks I have edited my post. app/router.js can be seen on my post now. I tried `main.dashboard` instead of `main.dashboard.index` in my `component.js`and still the problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the computed property is in the component.js, and you are doing `this.get('currentRouteName')`, but that property does not exist in components.

I believe you need to use the [router service](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/part-2/service-injection/#toc_the-router-service) in your component.

I'm assuming you are using pre-Octane syntax, so it should look something like this:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Component.extend({
   router: service(),

   dashboard: computed('router.currentRouteName',function() {
    if (this.get('router.currentRouteName') === 'main.dashboard.index') {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  })
});
```

I don't remember which version `RouterService` was first available, but I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry didn't pasted the full code. I already added inject in my code.

Comment: Did you try updating the code to use the `router` service as I shown in my code?

Comment: Yes same result :(

Comment: @abAL Are you sure that you are using the exact same code? The code snippet that you included in your question is missing `router.` both in computed property declaration as well as in getter.

Comment: Yes @jelhan I added `router.` in my code too.